# even distribution with naive shuffle?

Tags: go, shuffle

I'm shuffling an array of 3 int, 6 millions times. I keep count of each permutation of the array in a map. Code is below using go.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func randRange(min, max int) int {
    return rand.Intn(max-min+1) + min
}

func NaiveShuffle(arr *[3]int) {
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        e := randRange(0, 2)
        arr[e], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[e]
    }
}

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    m := make(map[[3]int]int, 6)
    arr := [3]int{-6,10,184}

    for i := 1; i <= 6000000; i++ {
        a := arr
        NaiveShuffle(&arr)
        m[a]++
    }

    for k, v := range m {
        fmt.Println(k, ":", v)
    }

}
```

Since I'm doing naive shuffle my understanding is it should **not** produce an even distribution of permutations. But this is what I get:

```
[184 -6 10] : 1000074
[184 10 -6] : 1000764
[-6 10 184] : 1000766
[10 184 -6] : 998090
[-6 184 10] : 1000479
[10 -6 184] : 999827
```

This shows each of the 6 possible permutations occurs about ~1M times. Why do I get what appears to be an even distribution ?

EDIT:  changed code to only seed once.  I now get:

```
[-6 184 10] : 999507
[184 -6 10] : 1000401
[10 -6 184] : 1002163
[10 184 -6] : 999236
[-6 10 184] : 999016
[184 10 -6] : 999677
```

EDIT2:  Thanks to hobbs, I realized I made a silly mistake.  I should shuffle `a`, not `arr`.  I now get:

```
[10 -6 184] : 1111056
[-6 10 184] : 888442
[184 -6 10] : 888576
[10 184 -6] : 1109896
[-6 184 10] : 1113148
[184 10 -6] : 888882
```

Comment: Sure.  Edited the code and posted new results.  Still looks even to me.

Comment: [as per docs](https://pkg.go.dev/math/rand#Source) Intn is likely to generated uniformly distributed random numbers. you may want to [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977354/generating-non-uniform-random-numbers)

Comment: I'm actually trying to generate non-uniform distribution.  By the way, a simpler way to generate uniform distribution is use fisher yates shuffle.

Comment: [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977354/generating-non-uniform-random-numbers) about non-uniform distribution may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're shuffling `arr` over and over six million times without restoring it to its original state in between shuffles — in other words, your six million trials aren't *independent*. Even though each shuffle has an uneven distribution of permutations, composing those permutations on top of each other six million times results in a distribution that's quite close to uniform.

Comment: Right on.  What a dumb mistake I made.

Answer (score 0):

Even you restoring it to its original state. its not a random event:

let us list all cases:

```
    m := map[string]int{}
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 3; j++ {
            for k := 0; k < 3; k++ {
                a := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
                a[i], a[0] = a[0], a[i]
                a[j], a[1] = a[1], a[j]
                a[k], a[2] = a[2], a[k]
                m[a[0]+a[1]+a[2]]++
                fmt.Printf("%v\n", a)
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", m)
```

result:

```
map[abc:4 acb:5 bac:5 bca:5 cab:4 cba:4]
```

it have all  `3*3*3` = 27 cases
but only have C(3,1) = 6 result
it must be not equal(4:5)..

Comment: This explains why it should be biased distribution but doesn't answer the question.  My test is wrong and I have edited my post to explain what I did wrong.